# iPhone Custom cell with UISegmentedControl

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have created a custom cell with a UISegmentedControl on it and loaded the cell like,

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

SegmentedCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) 
{
    NSArray *cells =[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SegmentedCell" owner:nil options:nil];

    for (UIView *view in cells) 
    {
        if([view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        {
            cell = (SegmentedCell *)view;
            [cell.SegmentedControl addTarget:self
                                                  action:@selector(segmentedControlChanged:)
                                        forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];        


        }
    }
}

cell.textLabel.text = @"Sample";
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

The custom cell successfully loaded and I get the action of the SegmentedControl.
But when I scroll the table view, state of the SegmentedControl is changed.

Comment: It's because you are reusing cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you scroll a tableview that uses dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier, you aren't actually saving all the different cells. To fix your problem you need to implement a few things.

- Set your segmented control up to store its value to a variable every time it is pressed.
- Put this value into an array
- In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, get the variable out of the array and set the segmented control's value to this value of the variable.